# data option in sassOptions stopped working in gatsby-plugin-sass after upgrading to v3 and replaced node-sass with sass

Tags: sass, gatsby, sass-loader, gatsby-plugin

I decided to remove `node-sass` from my gatsby project and use `sass` instead. I followed what is mentioned [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sass/#v300) for v3. I removed `node-sass` and now I have these versions in my `package.json`:

```
"gatsby-plugin-sass": "3.1.0",
"sass": "1.32.5",
```

I need to be able to write some @use or @import rules ONCE for global variables/mixins/functions so I can use them in all my scss files and so I won't have to repeat the same rules over and over again.

With `node-sass` something like this worked:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    includePaths: [`${__dirname}/src/styles`],
    data: `@import "globals.scss";`,
  },
},
```

After the upgrade, the `includePaths` attribute does work but the `data` does not and I get errors from my scss files about "missing" variables:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [`${__dirname}/src/styles`],
      data: `@use 'globals' as *;`,
    },
  },
},
```

If I insert the rule `@use 'globals' as *;` in each scss file the errors disappear and everything works as expected but I don't want to insert this line and modify all my sass files.

I am pretty sure that the issue has to do with `sass-loader` and this statement ([documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions)) but I can't figure out how to make it work and why it worked before:

> ℹ️ Options such as data and file are unavailable and will be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#900-2020-07-02), `data` option has been renamed to `prependData` and then removed in favor of `additionalData`. So:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    additionalData: `@use 'globals' as *;`,
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [`${__dirname}/src/styles`],
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: You are right about the name of the attribute. It has to be `additionalData` but you have to put it outside of the `sassOptions` and inside `options` in order to work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MakisK. It did indeed need be be a level up in the options object rather than the sassOptions object.