# Why are my global style modules being imported multiple times?

Tags: css, sass, gatsby, sass-loader

I have tried to set up some global Scss in my Gatsby application, but it looks like after doing this i am seeing some odd behaviour in dev tools:

[image: u]

You can see that my global styles are appearing and being overwritten multiple times.

It is a Gatsby app so i am using `sass-loader` and the default `dart-sass`.

Here is how i have configure my `gatsby-config.js` file to allow me to use these global styles based on this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65904094/12119984

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
     ...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        additionalData: `@use 'main' as *;`,
        //allow mixins, variables etc to be accessible globally
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: [`${__dirname}/src/styles/sass`],
          // data: `@import "main.scss";`,
        },
      },
    }...
```

I the use `@forward` along with `@extend` to get it all working in my module.scss files. My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My global styles are in `base.scss` and I import them into `main.scss` using `@forward`:

```
@forward "base";
@forward "layout";
@forward "components";
```

As an exmaple, here is my `index.module.scss` file where i then use these global styles:

```
.sectionHome {
 ...
  h1 {
    background-color: $color-secondary;
    @extend .uMarginBottomLarge;
    @extend .headingPrimary;
  }
}
```

It seems like a reasonable approach to me to use some global styles but to extend them into local sccs module classes, so can anyone explain to why these global styles are being applied several times?

Answer (score 0):

The `@forward` rule, according to the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward):

> The `@forward` rule loads a Sass stylesheet and makes its mixins,
> functions, and variables available when your stylesheet is loaded with
> the `@use` rule. It makes it possible to organize Sass libraries across
> many files, while allowing their users to load a single entrypoint
> file.

So basically, each time you are requesting a CSS module in some component, you are importing all the nested extensions (`@extend` and `@use`). Moreover, because of React's component extensions, you may also nest styles when importing nested components (`Button` in `Layout`, `Layout` in a `index.js`, etc)

Global styles in CSS apply exactly in the same way as CSS "standard" files, as you can see in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-global-styles/), extending its documentation, you will need to add the following in your `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import "./src/styles/sass/main.scss"
```